# PHP variable concatenation

Tags: php, string-concatenation

I'm trying to change a hardcoded variable value to dynamic, but can't seem to get the concatenation correct...

The hardcoded value is...

```
$token = "../wp-content/themes/mytheme/styles/test/sidebar";
```

And I'm trying to replace that with...

```
$token = ".get_bloginfo('template_directory')."styles/test/sidebar";
```

But its not working the same as when I hardcode the value.

What am I missing?

Here's the rest of the code (the imagegif function never fires with the dynamically generated variable...

```
$color = imagecolorallocate($img, $info["red"], $info["green"], $info["blue"]);
    for ($i = $startPixel-1; $i < $endPixel; $i++)
    {
        imagesetpixel($img, $i, 0, $color);
    }

    imagegif($img, $token.'.gif');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$token = get_bloginfo('template_directory') . "styles/test/sidebar";
```

The `.` is the concatenation operator, so you wouldn't want the get_bloginfo() function inside of quotes.  This assumes the function returns a string that ends in a `/`

Comment: Thanks Fosco, I missed that. Also had to put a "/" in front of "styles".

Answer (score 0):

```
$token = get_bloginfo('template_directory')."styles/test/sidebar";
```

Is that what you mean?  You had the function as a string instead of a function.

Answer (score 0):

From your code:

```
$token = ".get_bloginfo('template_directory')."styles/test/sidebar";
```

This line has a a stray quote and period at the beginning. You probably wanted to do:

```
$token = get_bloginfo('template_directory') . "styles/test/sidebar";
```

Function calls cannot be within strings, and the concatenation operator (`.`) must be outside of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Only strings should be wrapped within quotes.

```
$token = get_bloginfo('template_directory') . "styles/test/sidebar";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your concatination is a bit off.

Try:
`$token = get_bloginfo('template_directory') . 'styles/test/sidebar';`

Comment: "Your concatination is a bit off."... is that not the question ?

Comment: Maybe I meant his style of concatenating being a bit weird. But yeah, that was the question I guess ;-)